# Maximizing an absolute value of some complex polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, optimization, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Let $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} $ be any complex number, $ R > 0 $ some positive real. I want to find maxima of absolute value of some polynomial on the circle:

$$ \max (|x-1| |x-\lambda|) = \max| x^2 - (\lambda + 1)x + \lambda | = \max|P(x)|, $$
where $ |x| = R\ $ and  $\ P(x) = x^2 - (\lambda + 1)x + \lambda $.

It is not hard to find maximal value for concrete values of $R$, but I want it as function of $R$ and $\lambda$. I tried two things.

Firstly, polar coordinates: $ x = R e^{i \phi} $, $\lambda = L e^{i\psi} $. After some calculations I got the following equation:

$$ (L^2 + R^2) \sin(\phi) + L(1 + R^2) \sin(\phi - \psi) - 2LR\sin(2\phi - \psi) = 0. $$

We have to solve it for $\phi$. I don't know, how to do it (neither does Wolframalpha).

Secondly, I notice that if $x_m$ is the point of maxima on the circle, then

$$ Arg \frac{P(x_m)}{P'(x_m)} = Arg (x_m). $$

The reason is that in other way we could step a little inside the cirle and increase the $ |P(x)| $ (it is almost obvious if you draw the picture). But that would be contrary to the maximum modulus principle ($ P(x) $ is holomorphic). That gives us folowing:

$$ \frac{x_m^2 - (\lambda+1)x_m + \lambda}{2x_m^2 - (\lambda+1)x_m} \in \mathbb{R}_+. $$
And again, I do not know, what can you do next.

Maybe there is some geometry approach?

Comment: "*geometry approach?*" $\;-\;$ Don't think that's too likely. The locus of points with constant product of distances to two fixed points is a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval), so geometrically the problem is to find the largest Cassini oval with foci at $\,1, \lambda\,$ which is tangent to the circle of radius $R$.

Comment: why do you expect a "reasonable" answer in full generality (eg formula or such)? the question of characterizing entire functions by maximum modulus on circles is quite difficult even for polynomials and especially when the coefficients are not all real like here for generic $\lambda$

Comment: @Conrad well I expected it because this problem seemed to me almost obvious. But now after several failed attempts I am thinking that there is really no general formula.